# Copy from search mode to ex mode

Tags: copy, command, vim

While in the "`/`" mode to search, what should I do if need to copy it to the ex mode. E.g. I searched for `/ab.*xy`, now I need it as `%s/ab.*xy/.../g`.

My intention is to test my search and then use that for a search replace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `/` register, in ex mode press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>

[Ctrl-R](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html) allows you to insert the contents of a register, and the `/` register contains the last search pattern used.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can leave the search portion blank:

```
:/foo
:s//bar
```

The first line finds "foo", as you'd expect.  Since you left off the search string in the second line, it just re-uses the same search, replacing "foo" with "bar".  I believe this works anywhere you type a search string -- if it's blank, that means re-use the previous search.